# ¿Cuál es la diferencia semántica entre "Pérdida de Fase" y "Fase Perdida"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, frase

Estoy tratando de identificar cuál es la diferencia semántica entre estas dos frases (sin mayor contexto, solo las frases en sí). La frase *fase perdida* es fácil de describir: la frase denota una acción que ya pasó. Es decir, la frase indica que la fase ya se perdió.

Sin embargo, estoy teniendo problemas para describir adecuadamente, o en otras palabras entender completamente el significado de la frase ***pérdida de fase***. No sé si la frase denota algo que puede potencialmente pasar, o que está pasando, o alguna otra semántica.

¿Cómo describirían ustedes la frase *pérdida de fase*?

Comment: En la frase "pérdida de fase", el núcleo es "pérdida", por lo que la frase de refiere al acto o momento en que se pierde la fase. En contexto, se podría decidir si las frases son intercambiables o no.

Comment: @Gustavson entonces, podría decir que la frase "Pérdida de fase" se refiere al acto de perder la fase? En otras palabras, se podría generar una alarma que dijese "Pérdida de fase" en el momento en que se pierde la fase? O mas bien "Pérdida de fase" se usaría para describir el tipo de alarma pero no como el texto de la alarma en sí?

Comment: pérdida de fase o fallo de fase=electricidad (voltaje) y motores.

Comment: pérdida de peso y peso perdido.

Comment: Lambie ha dado un buen ejemplo. En la práctica, si bien son sintácticamente diferentes, las dos frases pueden a veces usarse en forma indistinta. Se puede decir: *Está débil por la pérdida de peso/por el peso perdido*. Del mismo modo, la alarma puede llamarse: *Pérdida de fase* o *Fase perdida* (en ambos casos queda claro que se perdió una fase).